# Selecting all columns of last row (tr) of a HTML table without the first column (td)

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to select the HTML for last row of a table without the first column.

For example, if the table looks like this -

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col21</td>
    <td>col22</td>
    <td>col23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The output should be -

```
<td>col22</td>    <td>col23</td>
```

The closest I could get is  -

```
var actions = $("table tr:last:not(:first-child)").html();
```

But this is printing all the columns. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: i think your question is not being clear. how can a <tr> not have the first column? if so, do you mean the <tr> is empty?

Answer (score 2):

The `:not(:first-child)` should be on the `td`s of the last row, not on the row itself.

`var actions = $("table tr:last td:not(:first-child)").html();`

Comment: This only selects the second column of the last row. What I want is all columns of last row except the first column.

Comment: No. It selects all the columns that are not `first-child`.

Comment: Let's try to check. What do you get from `$("table tr:last td').length` (all the colums) and what do you get from `$("table tr:last td:not(:first-child)").length`?
 (should be all minus 1)

Comment: Please see this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzv2a9dm/). It alerts only the second column.

Comment: It gets the columns right. change the `html()` to `length` and you'll see you get 2 columns. The point is that the `html` function returns only for the first element. Take a look on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option,  get tds of last row which will return array and just loop through tds and console every column except first column

```
var actions = $("table tr:last td").each(function( i, val ) {
  if(i !==0){
      console.log($(this).html());
  }
})
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zJxrGv

code sample for reference

```js
var actions = $("table tr:last td").each(function( i, val ) {
  if(i !==0){
      console.log($(this).html());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```